# What are the possible dimensions of all $n \times n$ matrices such that $A\vec{x} = \vec{0}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $\vec{x}$ is any vector in $\mathbb{R^n}$, what are the possible
>   dimensions of the space $V$ of all $n\times n$ matrices $A$ such that
>   $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$?

I'm confused about a couple of things. First, isn't a dimension of the space $V$ the number of $n\times n$ matrices in a basis for $V$? So how do we speak of multiple dimensions for the same space? In terms of solving the problem, I think the answer is that $V$ is $n$ dimensional, since a basis could be $n$, $n\times n$ matrices such that the first one has the first row equal to $-x$, the second has the second row equal to $-x$, etc. (and all other rows equal to $\vec{0}$).

Answer (score 1):

The set of $n\times n$ matrices is itself a vector space (a different one than $\mathbb R^n$), because you can add matrices, and multiply them with a number, and they fulfil all the rules you need for a vector space. This vector space is often denoted $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$.

Now the space $V$ in the question is defined for a given vector $\vec x$ as the subspace of $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ which fulfils $A\vec x=\vec 0$. This space obviously depends on the vector $\vec x$, that is, there is not just *one* such space, but a separate one for each vector $\vec x$ (for any pair of linear independent vectors, there exists a matrix that maps one of them to $\vec 0$, but not the other). This answers your question how you can have different dimensions: There are different spaces, one for each vector $\vec x$.

Actually what I've argued for above is strictly only that the *sets* $V$ are different; one would additionally have to show that each $V$ is indeed a subspace if $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, which isn't that hard. However from the formulation of the question, I suspect you may take that as a given (probably because it was proven earlier in the course or book the given question origins from).

OK, so we have different spaces $V$, one for each vector $\vec x$, and therefore it makes sense for each of them to ask for the dimension. Now the dimensions cannot be arbitrary (for example, they obviously cannot be larger than the dimension of $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$. Indeed, the spaces $V$ for many vectors $\vec x$ will have the same dimension (but not all of them; think for example of the vector $\vec 0$).

The question now asks for all dimensions you can have for $V$ if $\vec x$ can be an arbitrary vector.

Comment: When $\vec{x} = 0$, is the dimension $n^2$, and for any other $\vec{x}$ the dimension is $n$? I'm trying to also consider the standard vectors $e_1,...,e_n\in \mathbb{R^n}$ equal to $\vec{x}$, but I don't think these would have a special effect on the dimension.

Comment: @JennParker: The dimension for $\vec x=0$ you've got right, but in the other cases you're wrong. Hint: What matrices will map the vector $(1,0,\dots,0)^T$ to $\vec 0$?

Comment: Any matrix that has a $\vec{0}$ as its first column? Does this make the dimension $n-1$?

Comment: @JennParker: You're right about the form of the matrix, but not the dimension. Hint: How many matrix elements can you still choose freely?

Comment: I suppose that would be $n^2-n$. So are our choices for the dimension just $n^2, n^2-n,$ and $n$?

Comment: The $n^2-n$ is right. The $n$ is not. Hint: What happens for a basis change?

Comment: Is it that we have $n^2,n^2-n,n^2-2n, ..., 0$? Because I can see that $\vec{x}$ can also take $(1,1,0,...,0)^T$, $(1,1,1,0,...,0)^T$, etc.

Comment: No. $(1,1,0,\ldots,0)^T$ will also be sent to $\vec 0$ e.g. if the first column is all $1$ and the second column is all $-1$. To elaborate on my previous hint: Is it possible to change the basis to one having $\vec x$ as basis vector? And what happens to dimensions when you change the basis?

Comment: What if we have that the matrix is diagonal such that each diagonal element is $-\vec{x}$. I'm not sure how this changes the dimension, though, to be honest. I don't know if I'm on the right track here.

Comment: That matrix would not do a basis change. But then, you don't need to explicitly find a matrix that does it. You just have to answer the question: "Does there exist a basis for $\mathbb R^n$ that has $\vec x$ as basis vector? About the dimension: Is the dimension a property of the space, or just a property of the individual basis?

Comment: I don't think there exists a basis for $\mathbb{R^n}$ that has $\vec{x}$ as a basis vector. Does this imply that the dimensions are just $n^2$ and $n^2-n$?